# adding PowerShell command to batch file

Tags: powershell

I have batch file which I usually execute from command line. Now I want add the following PowerShell command to the existing batch file. The PowerShell command is working fine when I execute from the PS terminal, but I'm having problem when I add to the batch file.

```
(Get-Content "C:\IN\mypath.txt" ) -Replace "\*ALTTIME\S* |\*ALTDATE\S* |\*CRTIME\S* |\*CRDATE\S* |\*IPPROCS\S* |\*OPPROCS\S*" | Set-Content "Out\mypath.txt"
```

Comment: this is what I tried
powershell -command "& {&'(Get-Content "C:\IN\mypath.txt" ) -Replace "*ALTTIME\S* |*ALTDATE\S* |*CRTIME\S* |*CRDATE\S* |*IPPROCS\S* |*OPPROCS\S*" | Set-Content "Out\mypath.txt"}"

Comment: PowerShell is superior to cmd.exe. I recommend simply switching over to using PowerShell instead of trying to run PowerShell from cmd.exe.

Comment: Ideally I agree with @Bill_Stewart, but if you feel that you absolutely have to run that from within a batch file I would suggest saving it as a script (.ps1 file), and then running that script from the batch file. I can understand not wanting to part with a functional batch file that just needs to do a little more, and not wanting to have to re-write the whole thing in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your batch file:

```sh
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypasss -Command "(Get-Content 'C:\IN\mypath.txt' ) -replace '\*ALTTIME\S* |\*ALTDATE\S* |\*CRTIME\S* |\*CRDATE\S* |\*IPPROCS\S* |\*OPPROCS\S*' | Set-Content 'Out\mypath.txt'"
```